# Eliminating re-implementation of methods from the built class in Builder, while keeping it with nested calling

Tags: oop, design-patterns, builder

I have a class that has to be checked for being set for all of the variables, while more variables that must be set could be added:

```
class A{
   setVar1();
   setVar2();
   setVar3();
}
```

I have to check that all three sets were called before building it.
How can I create a Builder that:

A. won't have to re-call the above methods again (like implementing inside builder another setVar1() setVar2() which will call those from A - this is a hell for future maintenance to me to implement each of those setters twice). So bad example for me here would be:

```
class ABuilder{
   build(){...}
   builderSetVar1(){...} //HELL NO!
   builderSetVar2(){...} //NO NO NO!!!
   ...
}
```

B. Will check before building that all must have members are set (the user of the package, won't be able to have incomplete A)

C. Will allow nested one-line building of A (Builder...SetVar1(...)....SetVar2(...).build())

Is it even possible to achieve all of those three goals? I tried too many possibilities and in every solution

All in object oriented.

Comment: The whole point of the builder pattern is to have the mutators in the builder, have the build() method check that everything mandatory has been set, and finally build an immutable object, which thus doesn't have setters.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer offline:

I'll have to do the setters inside the builder and simply expand each time the constructor of the built object. In the end, I'll be able to do build and check that everything is set upon building.

I think it's the first design pattern I've really understood.